# Query for documents where array size inside array is greater than 1

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to find if any documents present and size more than one for a list which is inside two other lists in Mongo.

this is how my collection looks like:

```
{
    "value": {
        "items": [
            {
                "docs": [
                    {
                        "numbers": [
                            1,
                            2
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "numbers": [
                            1
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to use this query and it did not work:

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({"value.items.docs.numbers":{ $exists: true, $gt: {$size: 1} }})
```

What should be the ideal query to search if more than one item present inside list of list.

Comment: The question is ot clear, is this https://mongoplayground.net/p/3MbIQpD_9FE you are looking for?

Comment: @varman it is checking condition on value inside `numbers` field, see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rsvwVc_aRZC) will not return anything because all value inside `numbers` fields are less than 1.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to Accept your Answers to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- You are checking condition in nested array, for that nested `$elemMatch` condition will help to check conditions
- `$size` allow only number as input so `$not` will help in negative condition
- `$ne` to check array size should not [] empty

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').find({
  "value.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      docs: {
        $elemMatch: {
          numbers: {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: [],
            $not: {
              $size: 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QZlRgqfEgZU)